# ionic2: present a modal from popover, modal can't dismiss

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, popover

i present a modal from popover,code below is written in popover:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProjectDetailAddPage, {
     data: this.datas,
});
modal.present();
```

project-detail-add.html:

```
<ion-content style="background-color: white;" text-center>
    <ion-item no-lines style="margin-top: 2em;">
        <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()" clear>
        <span ion-text style="font-size: 15px;">确定</span>
    </button>
</ion-item>
```

ProjectDetailAddPage.ts

```
dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

`dismiss()`can't be invoked, but it can be invoked when i present modal from a general page not popover.i don't know how to solve this problem.

ios simulator environment is not ok, the browser environment is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem,when present a modal from a popover,you should dismiss the popover, in popover page, code modified like this:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProjectDetailAddPage, {
     data: this.datas,
});
modal.present();
this.viewCtrl.dismiss()
```